# Counting customers that have sales in the same products

Tags: dax

The data table has customers, products sales etc.
Based on a slicer selection products i want to count how many customers have sales in all selected products.
As below i only want to count customer B because he is the only one having all selected products

```
Customer a Product a product b product c
A.            1                 1
B.            1        1        1
C.                     1
D.            1                 1
E.            1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it on power query side... totally dynamic...

```
    let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTIEYjAVqxOt5AQVMISLOMOkgRSI74KuxRVJi1JsLAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Customer = _t, #"Product a" = _t, #"product b" = _t, #"product c" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer", type text}, {"Product a", Int64.Type}, {"product b", Int64.Type}, {"product c", Int64.Type}}),
    count_columns = Table.ColumnCount(Source)-1,
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Customer"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Customer"}, {{"Total Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Total Count] = count_columns )
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

OKay. I think Your table is this:

[image: Table]

Then You need this dax code:

```
CustomerHavingAll3Products =
VAR Onlya =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Product'[Customer] ), 'Product'[Product a] <> 0 )
VAR Onlyb =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Product'[Customer] ), 'Product'[Product b] <> 0 )
VAR Onlyc =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( 'Product'[Customer] ), 'Product'[Product c] <> 0 )
VAR CombinedAll =
    INTERSECT ( INTERSECT ( Onlya, Onlyb ), Onlyc )
RETURN
    COUNTX ( CombinedAll, [Customer] )
```

If we test it on a table visual:

[image: Result]

Please do not forget to click the down-pointing arrow on customer column on the filter pane, and ensure that "show items with no data" is checked, see the picture below

[image: GGT]

Comment: Hi sir, the problem is that the columns with products are not fixed but varying depending on the slicer selection. If i select 4 , will have 4 columns to be checked etc…

Comment: I don't think DAX is able to handle your request (not fixed number of columns) Please edit your post, and specify it. Share as much data as possible to convey your problem. Some people with knowledge will help you faster then. Stay safe!